# ActiveStorage::Attachment find resource by blob_id

Tags: ruby, attachment, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have the following model

```
class Document
  has_many_attached :previews
  ...
end
```

And I'm trying to find single elements there.
The problem is if I do:

```
@document.previews.find_by(blob_id: 22)
```

I get this error: `` undefined method `find_by' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many> ``

So I'm kind of forced to loop through enumerable:

```
@document.previews.find { |p| p.blob_id == 22 }
```

Is there any other (better/prettier) way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@ntonnelier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3201684/ntonnelier) I have a similar model, and with Rails 7.0.3 your first example works fine for me:

```
@document.previews.find_by(blob_id: 22)
```

Another couple of options that work are:

```
@document.previews.where(blob_id: 22)
@document.previews.blobs.find_by_id(22)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the blobs for a particular record via the `blobs` method, which gets you an `ActiveRecord` collection, and you can use `find` on that one.

Something like `@document.previews.blobs.find(22)` might work in your particular case.

Comment: thanks @eugen, but I need to find the Attachment instance, not the blob.

Comment: There's also an `attachments` method. Perhaps @document.previews.attachments.find might work.